# Calculate a given limit at $0$

Tags: limits

Calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_+} (\ln(\cos x))\ln x$$

I've tried to rewrite the expression in the limit as $\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\frac{1}{\ln x}}$ and then I applied l'Hospital's rule twice, but got nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: Try the reverse once: $\frac{ln(x)}{\frac{1}{ln(cox(x))}}$. Then apply L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the idea I mentioned in the comments,

$\lim _{x\to \:0_+}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{\tan \left(x\right)}{\ln ^2\left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)}}\right) =$

$\lim _{x\to \:0_+}\left(\frac{\ln ^2\left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)}{x\tan \left(x\right)}\right) =$

Apply the rule again,

$\lim _{x\to \:0_+}\left(\frac{-2\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\sec \left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)}{\tan \left(x\right)+x\sec ^2\left(x\right)}\right) =$

$\lim _{x\to \:0_+}\left(\frac{-2\cos \left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)}{\tan \left(x\right)\cos ^2\left(x\right)+x}\right) =$

And again,

$\lim _{x\to \:0_+}\left(\frac{-2\left(-\sin ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)+\cos \left(x\right)\left(\cos \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)-\sin ^2\left(x\right)\sec \left(x\right)\right)\right)}{-\sin \left(2x\right)\tan \left(x\right)+2}\right) =$

$\lim _{x\to \:0_+}\left(\frac{-2\left(\sin ^2\left(x\right)+\sin ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)-\cos ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)}{\sin \left(2x\right)\tan \left(x\right)-2}\right)$

Putting value now,

$\frac{-2\left(\sin ^2\left(0\right)+\sin ^2\left(0\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(0\right)\right)-\cos ^2\left(0\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(0\right)\right)\right)}{\sin \left(2\cdot \:0\right)\tan \left(0\right)-2}$

Which simplifies to zero.